# How do I return a MemoryStream docx file MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, docx

I have a docx file that I would like to return after I make edits. I have the following code...

```
object useFile = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/File.docx");
object saveFile = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/savedFile.docx");
MemoryStream newDoc = repo.ChangeFile(useFile, saveFile);
return File(newDoc.GetBuffer().ToArray(), "application/docx", Server.UrlEncode("NewFile.docx"));
```

The file seems fine, but I am getting error messages ("the file being corrupt" and another stating "Word found unreadable content. If you trust the source click Yes"). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is the ChangeFile in my Model...

```
    public MemoryStream ChangeFile(object useFile, object saveFile)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(useFile.ToString());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
            {                    
                string documentText;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    documentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                documentText = documentText.Replace("##date##", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    writer.Write(documentText);
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(saveFile.ToString(), ms.ToArray());
            return ms;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you open the file at "~/Documents/savedFile.docx" directly in Word without the download? If yes, the issue is an incomplete/corrupt download. If not, you need to show us what is going on inside `repo.ChangeFile`.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the changes you've made are not being done correctly.

Comment: Note that there's a `MemoryStream.ToArray()` method you do not need to use `GetBuffer()`.

Comment: @0xA3 - I can open the file directly. I am thinking the download is incorrect but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @Lloyd - I took your advice and removed the GetBuffer() method and it worked! You should put that as an answer so I can respond and give you the appropriate credit. Thanks!

Comment: @MrM I've done that, also provided the MSDN quote explaining it a bit.

Answer (score 15):

I use a [FileStreamResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = fileName,

        // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
        // the browser to try to show the file inline
        Inline = false,
    };
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return new FileStreamResult(documentStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't use `MemoryStream.GetBuffer().ToArray()` use `MemoryStream.ToArray()`.

The reason why is `GetBuffer()` relates to the array used to create the memory stream and not the actual data in the memory stream. The underlaying array could actually differ in size.

Hidden on MSDN:

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused.
>   For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream
>   object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer is 256, not
>   4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use
>   the ToArray method; however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in
>   memory.

Comment: Your answer solved my bug: I used GetBuffer and was getting a huge line of NULLs as the last line. replacing GetBuffer with ToArray solved it! thanks!